# How can i troubleshoot web page on IPhone?

Tags: iphone, html

I have been working on a web site that i want to work on any device.  It works great on all my devices except my work IPhone.  Is there any kind of console or other trick I can use to troubleshoot why it is not working?  Something like chrome and firefox ctrl+shift+j would be nice.

Comment: What have you tried? please let us know what steps or process you have attempted to solve this issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Chrome Dev Tools you can emulate a multitude of devices with differing resolutions and other limitations: [Sitepoint blog regarding emulation](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-mobile-emulation-mode-chrome/)

Comment: thanks.  Tring to figure out.  Tutorial is 20 versions old.

Comment: The reason things were not working was because IPhone does not accept the let key word.  Your answer at least lets trouble shoot CSS problems.

Answer (score -1):

you can attempt to use emulation using most any browser F12 or Inspect  or the multitude of online ones (google it)

In chrome on PC hit f12 then Ctrl-shift-M

Comment: So i get downvotes with no explanation? when I said essentially the same as the accepted answer